# How can I backup all the data?

Tags: backup, eclipse, android

I have just got into Android App Development using Eclipse.

I have done some work and created a small app.

I would like to completely backup all the XML, Java and other files of my project.
How can it be done?

Will having an online backup of all the files present in my "Workspace" folder be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To backup the project:

```
Export -> Archive File in Eclipse
```

To import the project in another Eclipse editor

```
Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Select Archive File
```